# Prove that point C' and C on Rhombus are the inverse of each other

Tags: geometry, inverse

Let ACBC′be a rhombus with AC = CB = BC′= C′A. Let O be a
point belonging to the line CC′outside of the rhombus. Prove that the points C and C′
are inverse to each other with respect to the circle centered in O of the radius R, such that
$$R^2 = OA^2 −AC^2$$

To prove that C and C' are inverses of each other I know we have to show that:

$$OC * OC' = R^2$$
but im not sure how to find the lengths of OC and OC' or how to use the information given, I tried maybe using Pythagoras using the information given but it didnt make any sense. Not sure how else to proceed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the circle $\Gamma$ centered in $A$ with radius $r=AC$.

Write the **power** of point $O$ with respect to $\Gamma$ in two ways (see for example [here](https://www.worldscientific.com/doi/10.1142/9789814368971_0013)):

$$OC.OC' = dist(0,A)^2-r^2$$

In fact, the two circles, the circle of inversion and circle $\Gamma$ are orthogonal (in particular circle $\Gamma$ is globaly invariant in this inversion). This is visible on the figure below :

i.e.,

$$OC.OC'=OA^2-AC^2$$

what you wanted to establish.

[image]

Comment: Another connection between inversion and a (deformable) rhombus is the [Peaucellier linkage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peaucellier%E2%80%93Lipkin_linkage).

Comment: Any comment ?...